# How to get calling expression when tracing a Python function?

Tags: python, debugging, trace

When inside tracing function, debugging a function call, is it possible to somehow retrieve the calling expression?

I can get calling line number from traceback object but if there are several function calls (possibly to the same function) on that line (eg. as subexpression in a bigger expression) then how could I learn where this call came from? I would be happy even with the offset from start of the source line.

`traceback.tb_lasti` seems to give more granual context (index of last bytecode tried) -- is it somehow possible to connect a bytecode to its exact source range?

EDIT: Just to clarify -- I need to extract specific (sub)expression (the callsite) from the calling source line.

Comment: will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903751/how-to-see-complete-traceback/13903934#13903934

Comment: @Alexey: unfortunately no, the source line is not precise enough for me, I need to extract specific subexpression.

Comment: maybe if you paste the source line, associated bytecodes, and the instruction you are debugging, we can help you work out where in the source that instruction is coding for.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I'm not debugging any specific code, I want to create a visual expression debugger on top of Python tracing facilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how I finally solved the problem: I instrumented each function call in the original program by wrapping it in a call to a helper function together with information about the source location of the original call. Actually I was interested in controlling the evaluation of each subexpression in the program, so I wrapped each subexpression.

More precisely: when I had an expression `e` in the original program, it became

```
_after(_before(location_info), e)
```

in the instrumented program. The helpers were defined like this:

```
def _before(location_info):
    return location_info

def _after(location_info, value):
    return value
```

When tracer reported the call to `_before`, I knew that it's about to evaluate the expression at location represented by `location_info` (tracing system gives me access to local variables/parameters, that's how I got to know the value of `location_info`). When tracer reported the call to `_after`, I knew that the expession indicated by `location_info` was just evaluated and the value is in `value`.

I could have written the execution "event handling" right into those helper functions and bypass the tracing system altogether, but I needed it for other reasons as well, so I used those helpers only for triggering a "call" event in tracing system.

The result can be seen here: http://thonny.org

Answer (score 6):

Traceback frames have a line number too:

```
lineno = traceback.tb_lineno
```

You can also reach the code object, which will have a name, and a filename:

```
name = traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_name
filename = traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
```

You can use the filename and line number, plus the frame globals and the [`linecache` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) to efficiently turn that into the correct source code line:

```
linecache.checkcache(filename)
line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, traceback.tb_frame.f_globals)
```

This is what the [`traceback` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) uses to turn a traceback into a useful piece of information, in any case.

Since bytecode only has a line number associated with it, you cannot *directly* lead the bytecode back to the precise *part* of a source code line; you'd have to parse that line yourself to determine what bytecode each part would emit then match that with the bytecode of the code object.

You could do that with the [`ast` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse), but you can't do that on a line-by-line basis as you'd need scope context to generate the correct bytecodes for local versus cell versus global name look-ups, for example.

Comment: The thing is that line number (or source line itself) is not granular enough for me, I need to extract specific callsite from that line.

Comment: @Aivar: then you'd have to parse out the bytecode (from the `.f_code` object plus the offset). That's a lot more involved.

Comment: @Martin: I don't doubt it's involved, but do you know, does bytecode contain source locations at line level only or at character level? From Python documentation I got the impression that bytecode instructions have only source line numbers associated with them.

Comment: @Aivar: it has line numbers only.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, compiled bytecode has lost its column offsets; the bytecode index to line number mapping is contained in the `co_lnotab` line number table.  The `dis` module is a nice way of looking at the bytecode and interpreting `co_lnotab`:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('a, b, c', '', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
              9 BUILD_TUPLE              3
             12 RETURN_VALUE        
  ^-- line number
```

However, there's nothing stopping us from messing with the line number:

```
>>> a = ast.parse('a, b, c', mode='eval')
>>> for n in ast.walk(a):
...     if hasattr(n, 'col_offset'):
...         n.lineno = n.lineno * 1000 + n.col_offset
>>> dis.dis(compile(a, '', 'eval'))
1000           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)

1003           3 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)

1006           6 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
              9 BUILD_TUPLE              3
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Since compiling code directly *should* be the same as compiling via `ast.parse`, and since messing with line numbers *shouldn't* affect the generated bytecode (other than the `co_lnotab`), you should be able to:

- locate the source file
- parse it with `ast.parse`
- munge the line numbers in the ast to include the column offsets
- compile the ast
- use the `tb_lasti` to search the munged `co_lnotab`
- convert the munged line number back to (line number, column offset)

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's necromancy but I posted a similar question yesterday without seeing this one first. So just in case someone is interested, I solved my problem in a different way than the accepted answer by using the `inspect` and `ast` modules in Python3. It's still for debugging and educational purpose but it does the trick.

The answer is rather long so [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28255919/1814314)