# How can I get the calling expression of a function in Python?

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, introspection

For educational purpose, I would like to be able to print the **complete** calling expression of the current function. Not necessarily from an exception handler.

After some research, I ended up with this pretty straightforward piece of code:

```
import inspect
import linecache

def print_callexp(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        frame = inspect.currentframe()

        # method 1, using inspect module only
        print(inspect.getframeinfo(frame.f_back).code_context)

        # method 2, just for the heck of it
        linecache.checkcache(frame.f_code.co_filename)
        line = linecache.getline(
            frame.f_back.f_code.co_filename,
            frame.f_back.f_lineno,
            frame.f_back.f_globals)
        print(line)

        # there's probably a similar method with traceback as well
    except:
        print("Omagad")

a_var = "but"
print_callexp(a_var, "why?!", 345, hello="world")
```

Result:

```
['    print_callexp(a_var, "why?!", 345, hello="world")\n']
    print_callexp(a_var, "why?!", 345, hello="world")
```

It does exactly what I want, as long as the calling expression stands on a single line. But with multiple lines expressions, it will only get the last line, obviously needing me to dig the calling context even more.

```
# same example but with a multiple lines call
a_var = "but"
print_callexp(
    a_var, "why?!", 345, hello="world")
```

Which gives us:

```
['        a_var, "why?!", 345, hello="world")\n']
        a_var, "why?!", 345, hello="world")
```

**How could I properly print the complete calling expression?**

"Play with the lineno value and apply some regex/eval trick" is not an acceptable answer. I'd prefer something cleaner that just works. I don't mind having to import more modules as long as they are part of the Python 3.x standard library. But nonetheless I would be interested in any reference.

Comment: Not sure this was solved by the python dev team. When I'm troubleshooting exceptions in my code, they often only reference the last line of a multi-line function call. One option to try might be to iterate over the lineno, and eval the response until there are no syntax errors/exceptions thrown.

Comment: @Jonathan Yep... Thought so, hence the last bit of the question :)

Comment: This is not a simple problem to solve. You could try and parse the calling *file* into a [AST tree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), but what part of the expression is then the caller? Python allows for a wide range of dynamic calling conventions, for example.

Comment: I'd go with Martijn's suggestion of AST, and just print the entire statement for line *N*.  You might end up with an entire indented block, but better to print too much than too little.

Comment: [IPython](http://ipython.org) just prints several lines of context; 2 before and 2 after, or similar.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I suppose IPython just plays blindly with the lineno? Anyway, I'll give your AST approach a try.

Comment: Yup, you get an arrow by the line number from the frame and the context around that line.

Answer (score 4):

For the curious, here is my final working code for such an unproductive purpose. Fun is everywhere! (almost)

**I do not mark this as the accepted answer right away, in the hope someone can enlighten us with a better option in a near future...**

It extracts the entire calling expression as expected. This code assumes the calling expression to be a bare function call, without any magic, special trick or nested/recursive calls. These special cases would have made the detection part less trivial obviously and are out-of-topic anyway.

In details, I used the current function name to help locate the AST node of the calling expression, as well as the line number provided by `inspect` as a starting point.

I couldn't use `inspect.getsource()` to isolate the caller's block, which would have been more optimized, because I found a case where it was returning an incomplete source code. For example when the caller's code was directly located in **main**'s scope. Don't know if it's supposed to be a bug or a feature tho'...

Once we have the source code, we just have to feed `ast.parse()` to get the root AST node and walk the tree to find the latest call to the current function, and voila!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import inspect
import ast

def print_callexp(*args, **kwargs):

    def _find_caller_node(root_node, func_name, last_lineno):
        # init search state
        found_node = None
        lineno = 0

        def _luke_astwalker(parent):
            nonlocal found_node
            nonlocal lineno
            for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(parent):
                # break if we passed the last line
                if hasattr(child, "lineno"):
                    lineno = child.lineno
                if lineno > last_lineno:
                    break

                # is it our candidate?
                if (isinstance(child, ast.Name)
                        and isinstance(parent, ast.Call)
                        and child.id == func_name):
                    # we have a candidate, but continue to walk the tree
                    # in case there's another one following. we can safely
                    # break here because the current node is a Name
                    found_node = parent
                    break

                # walk through children nodes, if any
                _luke_astwalker(child)

        # dig recursively to find caller's node
        _luke_astwalker(root_node)
        return found_node

    # get some info from 'inspect'
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    backf = frame.f_back
    this_func_name = frame.f_code.co_name

    # get the source code of caller's module
    # note that we have to reload the entire module file since the
    # inspect.getsource() function doesn't work in some cases (i.e.: returned
    # source content was incomplete... Why?!).
    # --> is inspect.getsource broken???
    #     source = inspect.getsource(backf.f_code)
    #source = inspect.getsource(backf.f_code)
    with open(backf.f_code.co_filename, "r") as f:
        source = f.read()

    # get the ast node of caller's module
    # we don't need to use ast.increment_lineno() since we've loaded the whole
    # module
    ast_root = ast.parse(source, backf.f_code.co_filename)
    #ast.increment_lineno(ast_root, backf.f_code.co_firstlineno - 1)

    # find caller's ast node
    caller_node = _find_caller_node(ast_root, this_func_name, backf.f_lineno)

    # now, if caller's node has been found, we have the first line and the last
    # line of the caller's source
    if caller_node:
        #start_index = caller_node.lineno - backf.f_code.co_firstlineno
        #end_index = backf.f_lineno - backf.f_code.co_firstlineno + 1
        print("Hoooray! Found it!")
        start_index = caller_node.lineno - 1
        end_index = backf.f_lineno
        lineno = caller_node.lineno
        for ln in source.splitlines()[start_index:end_index]:
            print("  {:04d} {}".format(lineno, ln))
            lineno += 1

def main():
    a_var = "but"
    print_callexp(
        a_var, "why?!",
        345, (1, 2, 3), hello="world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You should get something like this:

```
Hoooray! Found it!
  0079     print_callexp(
  0080         a_var, "why?!",
  0081         345, (1, 2, 3), hello="world")
```

It still feels a bit messy but OTOH, it is quite an unusual goal. At least unusual enough in Python it seems.
For example, at first glance, I was hoping to find a way to get direct access to an already loaded AST node that could be served by `inspect` through a frame object or in a similar fashion, instead of having to create a new AST node manually.

Note that I have absolutely no idea if this is a CPython specific code. It should not be tho'. At least from what I've read from the docs.

Also, I wonder how come there's no official *pretty-print* function in the `ast` module (or as a side module). `ast.dump()` would probably do the job with an additional `indent` argument to allow formatting the output and to debug the `AST` more easily.

As a side note, I found this pretty neat and small [function](http://alexleone.blogspot.com/2010/01/python-ast-pretty-printer.html) to help working with the AST.